# Docker Wordpress CPU jumps when selecting featured image

Tags: wordpress, docker, server

I have a DO VPS with 1GB RAM and 1 CPU.

I started to see some issues when I selected a Featured Image. I lost the database connection, so I checked my stats both docker and DO CPU stats, and shortly after selecting an image of around 1meg in size, my wp container's CPU skyrocketed and either caused the memory to run out or just did not do anything?

Then had the following, when tried to run `docker ps -a`:

```html
runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x7f55471d3428 m=0

goroutine 0 [idle]:

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.systemstack_switch()
 /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:245 fp=0xc820020770 sp=0xc820020768
runtime.main()
 /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:126 +0x62 fp=0xc8200207c0 sp=0xc820020770
runtime.goexit()
 /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998 +0x1 fp=0xc8200207c8 sp=0xc8200207c0

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
 /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998 +0x1

rax    0x0
rbx    0x7f5547562700
rcx    0x7f55471d3428
rdx    0x6
rdi    0x17a
rsi    0x17a
rbp    0xea3bde
rsp    0x7ffdf52e7938
r8     0x7f5547563770
r9     0x7f5547ba8700
r10    0x8
r11    0x202
r12    0x2cfb050
r13    0xe6f464
r14    0x0
r15    0x8
rip    0x7f55471d3428
rflags 0x202
cs     0x33
fs     0x0
gs     0x0
```

Has anyone else seen something like this?

I have done a [LoadImpact](http://loadimpact.com/) test which went for 5 min without any issues.

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this?